# Javascript - How to parse json in graph api facebook from http get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm using graph api to search the group, here is http request:

```
var url ="https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=group&q=house&access_token=access_token&callback=FB.__globalCallbacks.f317bdb78&limit=5&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey".

$.get(url, function( resp ) {
   console.log(resp);//it's return resp
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(resp.data);//I got error here, resp.data is undefined
   console.log(obj);
});
```

Here it's response from graph API:

```
/**/ FB.__globalCallbacks.f317bdb78({"data":[{"name":"House Party !!!","privacy":"CLOSED","id":"881671771927203"},{"name":"KITTY'S HOUSE","privacy":"OPEN","id":"100126236854592"},{"name":"Full House Long Xuy\u00ean","privacy":"OPEN","id":"606749376035865"},{"name":"Housing Ho Chi Minh City (Saigon)","privacy":"CLOSED","id":"330339417123482"},{"name":"Ch\u0103n Drap House","privacy":"OPEN","id":"1397025403874006"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MAZDZD","after":"NAZDZD"},"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.0\/search?access_token=access_token&pretty=0&q=house&type=group&limit=5&after=NAZDZD"}});
```

How can I parse JSON data from response graph search facebook?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSONP (note `callback=?` GET parameter) then your code should be:

```
var url ="https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=group&q=house&access_token=access_token&callback=?&limit=5&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey";

$.getJSON(url, function( resp ) {
   console.log(resp);
});
```

or more generic:

```
var url ="https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=group&q=house&access_token=access_token&callback=?&limit=5&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey";

$.ajax({
   url: url,
   dataType: 'jsonp'
}).then(function(resp) {
   console.log(resp);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use JSONP in the first place?

```
var url ="https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=group&q=house&access_token=access_token&limit=5".

$.getJSON(url, function(resp) {
   console.log(resp.data);
});
```

would be perfectly fine IMHO...